# How to sort to know sort data by completeness rate level on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
id   feature_1    feature_2   feature_3    feature_4   feature_5
1           10           15          10           15          20
2           10          NaN          10          NaN          20 
3           10          NaN          10          NaN          20 
4           10           46         NaN           23          20 
5           10          NaN          10          NaN          20
```

Here's what I need, I want to sort data based on completeness level (the higher percentage data is not nan, is higher the completeness level) of the dataset, the str is will be ascending so make me easier impute the missing value

```
id   feature_1    feature_2   feature_3    feature_4   feature_5
2           10          NaN          10          NaN          20 
3           10          NaN          10          NaN          20 
5           10          NaN          10          NaN          20
4           10           46         NaN           23          20 
1           10           15          10           15          20
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you explain more `completeness rate level` ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the percentage data not missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = ({
    'A' : ['X',np.NaN,np.NaN,'X','Y',np.NaN,'X','X',np.NaN,'X','X'],           
    'B' : ['Y',np.NaN,'X','Val','X','X',np.NaN,'X','X','X','X'],
    'C' : ['Y','X','X',np.NaN,'X','X','Val','X','X',np.NaN,np.NaN],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.T.isnull().sum()
Out[72]:
0     0
1     2
2     1
3     1
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     1
9     1
10    1
dtype: int64

df['is_null'] = df.T.isnull().sum()

df.sort_values('is_null', ascending=False)
Out[77]:
A   B   C   is_null
1   NaN NaN X   2
2   NaN X   X   1
3   X   Val NaN 1
5   NaN X   X   1
6   X   NaN Val 1
8   NaN X   X   1
9   X   X   NaN 1
10  X   X   NaN 1
0   X   Y   Y   0
4   Y   X   X   0
7   X   X   X   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If want sorting by column with `maximal` number of `NaN`s:

```
c = df.isnull().sum().idxmax()
print (c)
feature_2

df = df.sort_values(c, na_position='first', ascending=False)
print (df)
   id  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4  feature_5
1   2         10        NaN       10.0        NaN         20
2   3         10        NaN       10.0        NaN         20
4   5         10        NaN       10.0        NaN         20
3   4         10       46.0        NaN       23.0         20
0   1         10       15.0       10.0       15.0         20
```

Comment: Why did U use na_position='first'? If U use sum null values as a key.

Comment: because `na_position='last'` is default value ;)

Comment: why Id 1 come before Id 4?

Comment: @NabihBawazir - I think `ascending=False` is missing.

Comment: I get those idea when @Cezary.Sz. If you make multilevel sorting it helps as well